# WPF data binding fails (no subscriber for PropertyChanged)

Tags: c#, wpf

I use WPF 4.5 and c# language after binding when I check subscribers for PropertyChanged event in my poco class its null and nothing in UI change after the poco class changes. why it is happening ? this is what I've done(sry for bad english)
my poco object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CafeTunes.models
{
    public class Status : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private CurrentMedia CurrentMediaValue;
        public CurrentMedia CurrentMedia
        {
            get { return this.CurrentMediaValue; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.CurrentMediaValue)
                {
                    this.CurrentMediaValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMedia");
                }
            }
        }

        private string playStateValue;

        public string playState
        {
            get { return this.playStateValue; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.playStateValue)
                {
                    this.playStateValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("playState");
                }
            }
        }

        public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my XAML :

```
 <TextBlock Name="SongNameText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="19" Width="85"/>
```

and this is where i do the binding:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow
    {

        public Status AppCurrentStatus = new Status() { playState = "sdfsd", CurrentMedia = new CurrentMedia() {Artist="sdas", SongName="asdas" ,Album="asdasd",FileUrl="asdasd",Format="asdasd"} };

        public MainWindow()
        {

                InitializeComponent();
                SongNameText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("playState")
                {
                    Source = AppCurrentStatus,
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                });

        }
   }
```

Comment: Where did you check in `MainWindow` constructor or after that?

Comment: I checked it in Status class :
`
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
`

Comment: I suspect you checked it before when UI get a chance to hook to the event. Put a button in your window and from handler and try to set the property `playState` of AppCurrentStatus object and see if at that time event was null or not.

Comment: Is the `playState` property ever changed after you create the binding?

Comment: yes because I put a breakpoint in OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Can you post the code from where you are changing property `playState`?

Comment: thank you guys the problem was I have been assigning a new object to AppCurrentStatus

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the DataContext.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = AppCurrentStatus;

    }
```

i would prefer declaring bindings in xaml

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding playState}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="19" Width="85"/>
```

btw if you bind to a TextBlock - Mode=TwoWay makes no sense

Comment: DataContext is not required when Binding source is provided explicitly.

Comment: you are right, did not see the source. but its not a common way for me. i usually have one datacontext for one view and not different sources for one view

Comment: Yeah, but this answer doesn't hold valid for OP's question. That's why I put the comment over here.